# lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found with node-gyp

Tags: node-gyp

`node-gyp configure` and `node-gyp build` exit without error. However, when I attempt to call the function, I get this error

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: <function_name>
  Referenced from: /Users/username/src/....    
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

Can someone guide me how to debug this? What could possibly cause this kind of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out it's an issue that the library I used is C so I have to wrap it up inside `extern`

sth like this

```
extern "C" {
    #include "lib/mylib.h"
}
```